# Not able to access Azure keyvault value

Tags: c#, azure, exception, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I am trying to get the value from the key vault.
I am getting this exception.
Message "ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed.
Status: 503 (Service Unavailable)
Content:"service_unavailable
error_description:Service not available because the machine is not connected to Azure. Connection status: Disconnected.

```
        string keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("keyVaultName");
        var kvUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";

        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
        var secretName = "testKeyVault";
        try
        {
            var clientIdRecord = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);

            string KeyvaultValue = clientIdRecord.Value.Value;
            return new OkObjectResult(KeyvaultValue);
```

this is my local settings.json

```
 {
 "IsEncrypted": false,
 "Values": {
 "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
 "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
 "keyVaultName": "DemoProjectVault"
 }
 }
```

can someone help me to fix this please..

Comment: Are you running this code inside Azure Function app?

Comment: yes,in azure function app

Comment: If yes, Add Function's app managed identity to Key vault access policy and re run the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@SiddheshDesai** mentioned in the comments, you need to add functions managed identity to the Key vault access policy.
**I made some changes to your code. I got the secret of my key vault**.

**Code:**

```c
using System;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Azure.Core;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Azure;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static class KeyVaultFunction
{
    [FunctionName("GetKeyVaultValue")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> GetKeyVaultValue(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
    {
        try
        {
            string keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("keyVaultName");
            var kvUri = "https://<keyvault_name>.vault.azure.net/";

            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            var secretName = "<keyvault_secrete>";
            var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);

            string keyVaultValue = secret.Value.Value;
            return new OkObjectResult(keyVaultValue);
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex)
        {
            return new StatusCodeResult((int)ex.Status);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new StatusCodeResult(500);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

With the above output **URL**, I got my **secret** of the key vault as below,

[image]

I gave permissions **On** to the managed identity in the function app at the Azure portal as below,

[image]

And given access to the function app in a key vault at the Azure portal as below,

[image]

I got the access to the function app in the key vault as below,

[image]

Then, I deployed this to the function app in the Azure portal and got the deployed successfully as below,

[image]

I ran the code in the function app at the Azure portal and got the secrete of my key vault as below,

[image]

Comment: @Dasari Kamali.